# How can I summon the Martian invasion?

Tags: terraria

What are some ways to summon the Martian invasion?

I have tried to stand in the biome that I first found the probe in but it wont spawn.

I have left it on for about 5 hours but when I go back to see if the event had begun it doesn't show up so any response would be helpful thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to manually summon a Martian Probe or a Martian invasion.

You can start the invasion by letting the probe scout you and then letting it get away, if you destroy it or follow it, the event will not start.

Martian Probes spawn randomly after the Golem has been defeated. However you can increase the chance of encountering one by increasing their spawn rate. This can be done by staying in the Space layer where they have a higher chance to spawn. Martian Probes spawn chances are also affected by water candles, battle potions and events such as the blood moon and the solar eclipse.

Ensure that you don't have minions as they can destroy the probe before it escapes and the event will never start. Also make sure that the Lunar Events are not active, the probe cannot spawn during this event.

Comment: And you might also want to note that there is, according to the wiki, a delay after defeating a martian invasion before probes will spawn again. Also that they only spawn in the outer thirds of the world (1 third on each side).

Comment: If there is a delay, it's pretty short, as I've triggered multiple invasions only minutes apart.